# How to make mobile app using primefaces mobile in eclipse?

Tags: android, primefaces, adt, jsf-2.2, primefaces-mobile

i am new to primefaces mobile please anyone guide me how to make application using primefaces in eclipse ...because primefaces uses .xtml pages so how to create .xtml page in eclipse in android environment i dont know..

Tools for Dev:
ADT + Eclipse
Primefaces mobile 0.9.4
JSF 2.1.24

Please guide me about primefaces mobile i am stuck here
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a primefaces app just like any other web app. Please take a look at this for reference : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/index.jsf 
Yes you can eclipse + andriod emulator for your testing stuff. Just create a file in eclipse with a XHTML extension and you will be done.

Comment: @Shreyash.I am getting same issue, you mean to say that by using   super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index3.xhtml");

Comment: @BlueGreen primefaces is a server side library for making good UI. You need to have maven dependency or jar files in your web project in the server side.

Comment: @Shreyash.. Thanks for your response .. Yes i know that i am asking how we can use primeface in place of HTML5 . Because parimeface tag has some <P> , <I> ,etc.... tags and i think without proper jar file it will show lot of error , so is any tutorial for beginner level.?

Answer (score 0):

[PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) Provide UI components for JSF Applications for mobiles and other device only not for Mobile Apps.

[Please Check this link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/index.xhtml)